# How to define and call a function in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've seen a bunch of questions related to this subject, but none of them offers anything that would be an acceptable solution (please, no loading external Groovy scripts, no calling to `sh` step etc.)

The operation I need to perform is a oneliner, but pipeline limitations made it impossible to write anything useful in that unter-language...

So, here's minimal example:

```
@NonCPS
def encodeProperties(Map properties) {
    properties.collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" }.join('|')
}

node('dockerized') {
    stage('Whatever') {
        properties = [foo: 123, bar: "foo"]
        echo encodeProperties(properties)
    }
}
```

Depending on whether I add or remove `@NonCPS` annotation, or type declaration of the argument, the error changes, but it never gives any reason for what happened.  It's basically random noise, that contradicts the reality of the situation (at times it would claim that some irrelevant object doesn't have a method `encodeProperties`, other times it would say that it cannot find a method `encodeProperties` with a signature that nobody was trying to call it with (like two arguments instead of one) and so on.

From reading the documentation, which is of disastrous quality, I sort of understood that maybe functions in general aren't serializable, and that is why you need to explain this explicitly to the Groovy interpreter... I'm sorry, this makes no sense, but this is roughly what documentation says.

Obviously, trying to use `collect` inside `stage` creates a load of new errors...  Which are, at least understandable in that the author confesses that their version of Groovy doesn't implement most of the Groovy standard...

Answer (score 2):

It's just a typo. You defined encodeProp**e**rties but called encodeProprties.

Comment: It's a typo in the example I copied to SO and edited. In the actual script I'm running it's correct.

Comment: @wvxvw then can you please clarify what exception you exactly get when trying to run that code? It works fine for me.